# Do I need to stop asking questions here?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've recently deleted two of my questions<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330398/name-lookup-for-scoped-enum-inside-class?noredirect=1#comment62179966_37330398), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327458/unsigned-char-overflowing-on-gcc?noredirect=1#comment62174141_37327458)</sup> because of upvoted irrelevant comments on my questions. For question one, I've received this feedback:

> [+3] The problem is that you are using the same name for both the enum
>   class and the struct member using the enum class. If you rename the
>   `assoc` struct member to `assoc_` it compiles fine.

Misses the point of the question. I'm asking about why it errors in one compiler and not another.

> [+4] I really wish people would stop declaring types and defining
>   variables of that type in the same statement. It only creates
>   confusion.

Irrelevant.

> [+1] I *almost* wish it weren't possible to define a variable in the
>   same statement with defining the type.

Irrelevant.

#### Question two:

> [+4] Is there any behaviour *in C*++ that contradicts your
>   understanding?

Cryptic comment.

> [+4] The signed byte -128 and the unsigned byte 128 would be
>   represented by the same sequence of bits: 10000000. Whether those bits
>   mean 128 or -128 is in the eye of the beholder (e.g. after a `cmp`, does
>   the compiler generate a `jb` or `jl`?).

Should be an answer not a comment.

> [+5] Well, yes. At the moment there's no question. You've stated a
>   language rule, and then you start talking about something that hasn't
>   anything to do with C++.

#### Do I need to stop asking questions?

I received these feedback relatively quickly after I posted my questions and they received a high number of upvotes in the same period of time. None of them seem to constructively address the question or how it can be improved, but are just venting for no particular reason. I really do not feel welcome here. I'm afraid if I ask another question the same thing will happen.

Comment: Um.  What are you trying to discuss?  It's not clear what this meta question is about.  Right now it reads like a complaint instead of a discussion were we can offer meaningful feedback.

Comment: What are "fee fees"?

Comment: Have you considered politely *debating* those comments - telling them that you're having a difficult time seeing how the comment is relevant to your question? I'm sure they wouldn't leave you hanging. Right now, your responses to the comments do nothing to indicate that you are not happy with them. (Yes, SO comments often come across as very curt. Polite tone is not the forté of many users here, especially in some tags (*cough* See slash see plus plus *cough*). In that specific aspect, there is indeed a need for *some* thick skin.)

Comment: I'm not here to say you are right or wrong or the commentators are right or wrong.  What I am here to say is, as an outsider to what just happened to you I seriously think the fact that someone is questioning whether he or she should stick around to ask questions only to get more downvotes and more snarky remarks is a BIG problem that SO seriously hasn't solved yet.  I don't care about the old links about how SO is going to change this to be more "nice".  It really hasn't worked because I see people like you sufferring with issues only to be downvoted into oblivion...but wait downvotes are...

Comment: For disagreements on meta...they don't mean you're wrong...I'll hear.  BS - I don't care if you've got that tucked away in some rule book or another thread that yet another person posts or links to.  It just doesn't work that way for people.  You're essentially shutting the doors on others and people will leave.this place in a heartbeat if they don't feel welcome.  Having issues on the main site, and then posting back on meta, only to get downvoted (which aside from you thinking it means such and such..its visually not appealing to have downvotes) and have more rough comments doesn't work.

Comment: Comments can be flagged for being too chatty or not constructive. If the comments really are off topic, flag them.

Comment: post on a public forum expect public comments. If you want to control how your answered - then go pay some one.

Comment: That doesn't mean SO doesn't have a problem with tone, @Dagon. (Not sure whether anything can be done about it, though.)

Answer (score 3):

> inb4 "grow a thick skin", "this is a site for professionals not your fee fees"

Sure, thick skin is helpful surviving Stack Overflow.

Why did you delete your (upvoted) questions? Too impatient waiting for answers?

You might have followed the advice from the upvoted comments, and either write your own answer based on the comment, or clarify your question.

---

> > [+4] Is there any behaviour in C++ that contradicts your understanding?

As mentioned above, clarify that in your question.

---

> > [+4] The signed byte -128 and the unsigned byte 128 would be represented by the same sequence of bits: 10000000. Whether those bits mean 128 or -128 is in the eye of the beholder (e.g. after a cmp, does the compiler generate a jb or jl?).

Take that and write your own answer based on it.

Comment: ... or responded to the comments asking them to clarify what they're talking about. (I don't have domain knowledge, but I can't believe they're all just venting unrelated nonsense. Some of them are very knowledgeable users.)